# cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-implicit-fallthrough" [-Werror]

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when I am cross compiling compute library on x86 for arm  by using SCons.
Here I am cross compiling this to run a  tensorflow model on armnn sdk.
How I can solve this error?
Please give me suggestion.

Comment: find where this flag is set end remove it. Apparently your compiler do not support this flag (probably old version of gcc). What build manager does this lib use?

Answer (score 3):

`-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` [was first added in gcc-7](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/10/wimplicit-fallthrough-in-gcc-7/). You are probably using an older version of the compiler, which does not recognize the option.

You have several options:

- Use later version of gcc
- Remove `-Wno-implicit-fallthrough` flag from gcc call
- Add [`-Wno-unknown-warning`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) to suppress the warning

Comment: A third option is to remove `-Werror` (Though if they know how to do that they know how to do the second one).

Comment: @prasanna you could also suppress the warning (see third option in extended answer)

Comment: how to cross compile compute library for arm by scons .

Comment: where i have to remove -Wno-implicit-fallthrough flag from gcc call

Comment: please give me  reply

Comment: @prasanna Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with SCons. Maybe this SO question will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611435/setting-compiler-specific-flags-in-scons.

Comment: @prasanna also see: https://scons.org/doc/1.3.1/HTML/scons-user/a4819.html#cv-CCFLAGS